# How to prevent default action Function button (F4, F5, etc) in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So. I tried to prevent execution of default action function in angular.js by using this code inside a page controller. I have put a reference to jQuery library before.

```
 angular.module('MainCtrl').controller('SellingCtrl', ['$scope', 
     function ($scope) {
         $('body').bind('keyup', function(e){

             var key = e.keyCode || e.key;

             if([115, 116, 117, 118, 119].indexOf(key) >= 0){
                   e.preventDefault();
             }

             console.log(key)
             console.log([115, 116, 117, 118, 119].indexOf(key) >= 0);
           })
      }]
  )
```

It's worked, the line `e.preventDefault()` does executed. The problem is it doesn't stop default button function like refresh(F5) or debug javascript(F8). 
So what function that i should use here ?

Comment: You might have to trap keydown or keypress events which are disticnt.

Comment: @Kolban - hey, i just change 'keyup' to 'keydown' and the whole things work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of keystroke events including:

- keyup
- keydown
- keypress

It is likely that you have to trap or handle some or all of them to achieve the desired function.

Comment: doesn't it make handler function fired more than one time ? I try to add keypress and keyup event, and it executes my function several times. In what circumstances that i will likely trap all of them ?

Comment: It depends on the effect you are trying to achieve.  If the goal is to disable function on a keypress, then without knowing what actually triggers the function you want to disable, you would want to disable the propagation of all events.  However, if you have confidence that only a subset of key events are being processed at a higher level, then you would be safe intercepting only them.

Comment: well. I tried the combination of those keystroke events. I think keyup is exactly what i need. 
Thank you anyway